# proving inequality $P\left( {\exists i \in \left\{ {1,...,n} \right\}{Y_i} \geqslant t} \right) \leqslant nP(Y \geqslant t)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let $(Y_i)_i$ i.i.d random variables ($Y$ is positive).

for $n\geq 1$ and $t\geq 0$ , show that :

$P\left( {\exists i \in \left\{ {1,...,n} \right\} : {Y_i} \geqslant t} \right) \leqslant nP(Y \geqslant t)$

i have no idea, some help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability there is an $i$ such that $Y_i\ge t$  is equal to $1$ minus the probability that **all** the $Y_i$ are $\lt t$.

So if $p=\Pr(Y\ge t)$, then the probability not all the $Y_i$ are $\lt t$ is 
$$1-(1-p)^n.$$
But by the [Bernoulli Inequality,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) we have $(1-p)^n \ge 1-pn$, and therefore $1-(1-p)^n \le pn$.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality may be more familiar to you in this form
$$\Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (Y_i\geq t)\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(Y_i\geq t).$$

Comment: Much better than mine!

Comment: yes, yes, i remember this formula. thanks

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, more natural to a probabilist anyway. ;)

Comment: @johnalex Glad I could help!